# Dynamically Calculate & Add value in a DataTable Column - ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a DataTable which is being bound from DB with the Columns: Id, Date, Credit, Debit.

I want to add new Column "Balance" and its value should be calculated for EACH Row by the formula; **[Balance in Previous row] - [Credit] + [Debit]**

I have done something like this:

```
dt; //Filled & having columns ID, Date, Debit, Credit
dt.Columns.Add("Balance");

foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    //What should I do here to apply above formula
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want the formula for the first row to be `Credit + Debit` since there is no previous row and adapt the formula you wrote for any other row. If so, this would be the safe way to do it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];

    decimal credit = 0, debit = 0, previousBalance = 0;
    decimal.TryParse(row["Credit"].ToString(), out credit);
    decimal.TryParse(row["Debit"].ToString(), out debit);

    if (i > 0)
        decimal.TryParse(dt.Rows[i-1]["Balance"].ToString(), out previousBalance);

    row["Balance"] = i == 0 ? credit + debit : previousBalance - credit + debit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working. And also I figured out the following solution and it also worked.


`for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if(i==0)
                dt.Rows[i][5] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][4]) - Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][3]); 
            else
             dt.Rows[i][5] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i - 1][5]) + Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][4]) - Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][3]);
        }`

Comment: @TalhaAhmed Well there may be multiple solutions, I don't even know what type are your credit, debit and balance so decimal was safe pick and TryParse is there to avoid any errors when getting values from your DataTable since you also didn't say if these columns are nullable. Your example might work, but it's not readable. In my opinion row["Balance"] column is more intuitive than row[5], don't you think? Anyways, glad you sorted that out. If my answer was helpful I'd appreciate if you accepted it as solution of your problem.